# About a linear map from $ \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove the  linear map $L : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is ***onto*** if and only if $L$ is ***one to one***.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. I didn't down-vote, but if I had to guess why some people have, it would be because you haven't asked a question. You've made a statement about what you want, implicitly saying that others should now get to work meeting your demands. On this site you will have more success if you ask a question. You will also have more success if you show some of the things that you have tried in your own efforts to answer that question.

Comment: Not only in *asking* is where success resides but also in showing some effort, giving some reasons/background of the problem, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. The trivial map $L : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $L(v) = 0$ is linear, but not one to one or onto.

---

For the new phrasing of the question. Suppose $L$ is linear. If $L$ is injective, then $\text{ker}(L) = \{0\}$. By the first isomorphism theorem, $im(L) \simeq \mathbb{R}^n / \{0\}$. This is a $n$-dimensional vector space. The only $n$ dimensional vector subspace of a $n$-dimensional vector space is the entire vector space. So $L$ is surjective.

Suppose that $L$ is surjective. Then again by the first isomorphism theorem, $\mathbb{R}^n / \text{ker}(L) \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$. So $\text{ker}(L)$ is a zero dimensional vector subspace. Hence $\text{ker}(L) = \{0\}$. $L$ is injective.

Answer (score 3):

That is false. Consider the map $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by
$$L(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=(a_1,\ldots,a_n+1)$$
This is both onto and one-to-one, but not linear.

---

You probably *meant* to ask about the fact that, **given** a linear map $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $L$ is onto  if and only if it is one-to-one. Note that the statements
$$A\iff B\text{ and }C$$
and 
$$A\implies (B\iff C)$$
are **different**.

In this discussion, we are using $A$ = "$L$ is linear", $B$ = "$L$ is one-to-one", and $C$ = "$L$ is onto"

Comment: Yes exactly, I edited my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is true not only for any linear operator on $\mathbb{R^n}$, but for any linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces of equal dimension.  This follows from the rank-nullity theorem, which states that given vector spaces $V$ and $W$, and a linear map $T: V \to W$,

$$\dim T(V) + \dim\ker T= \dim V$$

Fact: $T$ is one to one $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\ker T = \{0\}$